# How to get password value in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch password field like below:

```
xtype : 'passwordfield',
id : 'password',
name: 'password',
label : 'Password',
labelWidth : '40%',
```

I want to get the value of this field. I tried using getValue() method. But it is returning me null value.

In controller:

```
merchantPwd : '#password',
```

And then like this:

```
  var pwd = this.getMerchantPwd().getValue();
alert("password:" +pwd);
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

The only different between `passwordfield` and other input fields is its value is hidden by showing just meaningless characters, e.g dots or stars. Except this, it's just like other input field.

For example, try this in the Sencha Touch documentation code editor & live preview, it works.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Register',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    label: 'Email',
                    name: 'email'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    label: 'Password',
                    name: 'password',
                    id: 'abc',
                    value: 'abc',
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
Ext.Msg.alert(Ext.getCmp('abc').getValue());
```

So I think there might be some issues such as:

- The password field is blank (actually in this case it shows nothing but not null value)
- There're some problems with your controller code. Pay attention to `this` pointer.

Comment: i checked..but it is not coming..even if i am trying to get the value of TextArea Field, Email Field, it is returning me null.